# How to view the entire content of an array in a label (xcode 4.1)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, label

i'm programming in Obj-c with xcode4.1, i have an array with numbers in it, and i want to visualize all of them in a label...can anyone help me around this please?
thanks!

this is the code:

```
    combinedString=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *finalStringLabel=@"";

    for (i=0; i<=textLength; i++) {

        //character coding
        char myChar = [myString characterAtIndex:i];
        NSString *myCharS=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", myChar];
        int asciiCode=[myCharS characterAtIndex:0];
        NSString *asciiS=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", asciiCode];

        [combinedString addObject:asciiS];


    }
    finalStringLabel=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"", [combinedString componentsJoinedByString:@"."]];

    myLabel.text=finalStringLabel;
    [combinedString release];
}
```

Comment: what you have to face problem >?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
NSArray *yourArray;
NSString *createdString = [yourArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
myLabel.text = createdString;
```

Comment: at: char myChar = [myString characterAtIndex:i]; the program gives me this error "thred 1: Program recived signal:"SIGABRT"." and i got no warnings or errors. what should i do?

Comment: you can either just use my 3 line code or i think you should use char *myChar for that.

Answer (score 0):

As your array is `combinedString`,

```
combinedString=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

looks like you are providing values after this line or this is not a `property` (this is a local as you are releasing it later), and your code in not complete.

Anyways, 
You don't need to create an empty string and then assign new object to it, need to do as :

```
    myLabel.text=[combinedString componentsJoinedByString:@"."];
    [combinedString release];
}
```

Comment: how please feel free to tell.